# Get random wiki page from cloud functions

Tags: json, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I tried to get a random Wikipedia page over their API via Google Cloud Functions. The Wikipedia API works fine. This is my request:

> https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=random

For testing you can change the format to jsonfm in see the result in the browser. [Click here](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&generator=random) .

But it seems that my functions get destroyed even before the request was completely successfully. If I want to parse the data (or even if I want to log that data) I got a

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of json
```

The log look like (for example) that (no I haven't cut it by myself):

> DATA: ue||"},"query":{"pages":{"2855038":{"pageid":2855038,"ns":0,"title":"Thomas Fischer

Of course, that is not a valid json and can't be parsed. Whatever this is my function:

```
exports.randomWikiPage = function getRandomWikiPage (req, res) {
  const httpsOptions = {
    host: "de.wikipedia.org",
    path: "/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=random"
  };

  const https = require('https');
  https.request(httpsOptions, function(httpsRes) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + httpsRes.statusCode)
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(httpsRes.headers))
    httpsRes.setEncoding('utf8')
    httpsRes.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log("DATA: " + data)
      const wikiResponse = JSON.parse(data);

      const title = wikiResponse.query.title
      res.status(200).json({"title": title})
    });
  }).end();
};
```

I've already tried to return something here. Like [that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc) explained. But as I look into the node docs `https.request` don't return a `Promise`. So return that is wrong. I've also tried to extract the `on('data', callback)` into it's own `function` so that I can return the `callback`. But I haven't a success with that either.

How have to look my function that it return my expected:

> {"title": "A random Wikipedia Page title"}

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `json` comes through as a stream in chunks.  You're attempting to parse the first data chunk that comes back.  Try something like:

```
  https.request(httpsOptions, function(httpsRes) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + httpsRes.statusCode)
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(httpsRes.headers))
    httpsRes.setEncoding('utf8')
    let wikiResponseData = '';
    httpsRes.on('data', function (data) {
      wikiResponseData += data;
    });
    httpRes.on('end', function() {
      const wikiResponse = JSON.parse(wikiResponseData)
      const title = wikiResponse.query.title
      res.status(200).json({"title": title})
    })
  }).end();
};
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. Thank you, it works . Can you pease edit the `let wikiResponseData;` to `let wikiResponseData = "";`. Otherwise the `wikiResonseData` will be `undefined{THE_JSON_DATA}`

Comment: Okay should be changed.  Sorry it's been a bit since i've messed with streams